# Simple 2D Point Cloud visualisation with Point Cloud Library

Tags: point-cloud-library

What class/functions should I use to visualize a 2d point cloud? All the documentation online seem to only point to 3d point cloud visualization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, the visualization module of PCL is done for 3D point clouds. But, you can perfectly visualize a 2D pointcloud in 3D. You will just have one of the coordinate set to 0 (or any other constant).
Your point cloud will appear planar and, as the viewer is 3D, you will be able to move and rotate around it.

If you really need to constraint the camera, I think you will need to write your own visualizer using VTK. This will require more effort, especially if you are not familiar with the way VTK is working. (`vtkInteractorStyleRubberBand2D` is the type of 2D camera interactor that could be used.)